# Loop to sum values over a certain period time with additional values

Tags: loops, date, stata

I have a dataset called billing and payments, which I have appended together, then sorted by id, such that one will be able to view the bill charged to each id, and the payments made by each id.

Here is a snapshot of it: 
  [Dataset snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afx9L.png)

```
contractaccount printdate paymentdate billingperiod duedate payable payment
12345           01jan2015                    201501 15jan2015   100 
12345                       13jan2015                                    50
12345                       13jan2015                                    50
12345           29jan2015                    201502 13feb2015   150 
12345                       03feb2015                                   150
12345           05mar2015                    201503 20mar2015   100 
12345                       21mar2015                                    80
12345                       22mar2015                                    20
23456           15jan2015                    201501 31jan2015   200  
23456                       20jan2015                                   200
23456           12feb2015                    201502 28feb2015   220 
23456                       13feb2015                                   100
23456                       15feb2015                                   100
23456                       20feb2015                                    20
23456           10mar2015                    201503 20mar2015   200 
23456                       18mar2015                                   100
23456                       20mar2015                                   100
```

I intend to sum the payments made, if the payment is being made between the printdate and duedate, with the additional condition that the billingperiod corresponds to a print date, for example, sum the payments made by id 12345, between 01jan2015 and 15jan2015, provided that the billingperiod "201501" corresponds to the printdate 01jan2015.

I have tried the following code:

```
bysort contractaccount: gen paymentsum=sum(payment) if paymentdate<=duedate  & paymentdate>=printdate
```

but I still don't know how to add in the additional condition mentioned above. It also does not give me what I want, as the code generated a cumulative sum of payments for each id. Ideally, I'd like to generate an output that would show the sum of payments made for each id subject to all the date conditions aforementioned (for each billingperiod, what is the sum of payments made by each id).

I have a hunch I'd need to write a loop on this, which is another challenge as I'm still a new user of Stata.

Comment: Example data that can be copied and pasted would help your case. Most of the advice at http://www.statalist.org/forums/help applies here.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the advice! I've updated my query here